# How can I resolve the TypeScript error 'Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'' in my code?

Tags: typescript

I have the following simple function (`make`) that calls the `handle` function and is supposed to retry a number of times whenever that function throws. If the retries are exhausted, the `make` function should throw the error.

```
const handle = async (): Promise<string> => 'hi';

const make = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const MAX_RETRIES = 2;
  for (let idx = 0; idx <= MAX_RETRIES; idx++) {
    try {
      return await handle();
    } catch (err) {
      if (idx < MAX_RETRIES) {
        continue;
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I'm using TypeScript, which is complaining because the return type doesn't include `undefined`:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

For reference, [this is the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQzAEwDYFMYF4YIgTzGBgAoBKALhgAUAnEAWwEsJ0AeaWpsAcwD5sAgORwmQgNwAoSaEiwGCANaYceQsXJU6jFu07d+gmAG9JMGLOgwAsgEEAGgH0ASgFEAKs4CSrgMrYYACYpcwAzEFpSDFgmZAAPAIAGcRhYhLYcOyc3Tx9fFLSAakKyEzNzGChafDKKitp0KABXWjBcAHcEJlhEFAxyEIqAXwsEKGA4UnRaWlLTOvMmUNI0mDYbBxcPbz858oWLcChuJvRBupH0VFZag8q4enaYadpz4f2YIfKvofEgA) for the code above.

I'm looking for guidance on how to handle the return type for the function.

Note that:

- I don't want to change my tsconfigs (currently set to `strict`)
- I don't want to modify the return type to `Promise<string | undefined>`

My understanding is that the `make` function can only either return a `string` (inside the `try` block) or throw an error once the retries have been exhausted. If that's the case then where does the `undefined` that TS is asking for comes from? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything, it's just that the compiler isn't quite smart enough to understand that the loop will never terminate normally.

Comment: TS can't do the sort of counterfactual analysis with math it would need to understand what you're doing.  I'd suggest changing to something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGdJow) instead.  Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz - Blast, I tried to do something like that in the couple of minutes I had and somehow failed to come up with that simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that the `make` function can only either return a string (inside the `try` block) or throw an error once the retries have been exhausted.

I'm fairly sure you're right, but *TypeScript* can't quite follow logic that complex, so it (incorrectly, I think) sees a path through the function that doesn't do an explicit `return` and so implicitly returns `undefined` (wrapped in a promise).

You can solve it in a few ways:

1. Add a `return "";` at the end with a comment noting it'll never happen. (Blech.)
2. Add a `throw new Error("Logic error, this will never be reached.");` at the end.
3. Rewrite the function to make the final attempt more obviously a `return`-or-`throw` situation by using `<` instead of `<=` and then repeating the `return await handle();` at the end. (Not great to have to repeat it, but it's very simple.)

I don't think #1 or #2 need examples, but here's what #3 might look like:

```typescript
const make = async (): Promise<string> => {
    const MAX_RETRIES = 2;
    for (let idx = 0; idx < MAX_RETRIES; idx++) {
        try {
            return await handle();
        } catch (err) {
            continue; // I guess technically we don't need this, since
                      // the loop doesn't do anything else
        }
    }
    return await handle();
};
```

For me, #2 is the winner (or [jcalz's rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384387/how-can-i-resolve-the-typescript-error-function-lacks-ending-return-statement-a/76384457#comment134692628_76384387)), but any of them will make TypeScript happy, it's really a style choice.